# Varios filtros em uma regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Preciso validar um campo *input* que pode ter os seguintes formatos:

```
`D-1` ou `D-10` ou `D-1_1` ou `D-10_1` ou `D-1A` ou `D-10A`
```

As letras e números podem variar, mas sempre terão um desses formatos.

Comment: Vc quer verificar se o input terá apenas um desses formatos ou que contenha um desses formatos?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ehRMdv/1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use essa regex:**

```
([a-zA-Z]+-\d+_{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```

**Explicação:**

- `[a-zA-Z]+` Valida se existe uma ou mais de uma letra.
- `-` Valida se existe o caractere `-` após a letra.
- `\d+` Valida se existe um ou mais número.
- `_{0,1}` Verifica se após a sequencia anterior existe o caractere `_` caso exista ele entra no grupo de captura.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` Verifica se existem letras ou números após `_`, caso exista esses caracteres entram no grupo de captura.

[Você pode ver o funcionamento dessa regex aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/fWfdYn/3/)